# Import csv file into R data frame with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a csv file with a data frame:

```
pc2020 <- read.table("pc2020.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE)
```

This works ok, but the enconding is wrong, thus, I get all messed up accentuated characters.

So, I'm trying with:

```
pc2020 <- read.table("pc2020.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

That returns:

```
Error in read.table("pc2020.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8") : 
  no lines available in input
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table("pc2020.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8") :
  invalid input found on input connection 'pc2020.csv'
```

Comment: It is better trying to use `read.table()`, it uses to work for encoding issues!

Comment: And read.table() am I not using?

Comment: Sorry, I have seen you used it! Try `read_table()` from `readr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read.csv()` function with the same attributes you used with `read.table`. Except `fileEncoding` - in `read.csv()` you should write just `encoding = "UTF-8"`.

Also Duck's answer is suitable, too.

Comment: Yes, actually, I've solved the problem with read_csv2 from readr package.